# Extracting the file name from a full path string

Tags: string, bash

Let's say I have a string which represents the full path of a file:
 `full_path='./aa/bb/cc/tt.txt'`.

How can I extract only the file name `tt.txt`?

Please don't tell me to use `echo $full_path | cut -d'/' -f 5`.

Because the file may be located in a deeper or shallower folder.

The number, `5`, cannot be applied in all cases.

Comment: Hope this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32372307/2987755

Answer (score 0):

if you are comfortable with python then, you can use the following piece of code.

```
full_path = "path to your file name"
filename = full_path.split('/')[-1]
print(filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the parameter expansion functionality.

```
 full_path='./aa/bb/cc/tt.txt'
 echo ${full_path%/*}
```

That will give you the output

```
 ./aa/bb/cc
```

And will work any number of directory levels deep, as it will give you everything up to the final "/".

Edit: Parameter expansion is very useful, so here's a quick link for you that gives a good overview of what is possible: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe

Answer (score 0):

You can use this construct

```
echo "$full_path" | sed 's/\/.*\///'
```